# Where do SQL questions belong?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Should questions about SQL (the language, not the server) be asked on SF or SO?

There are a reasonable number of questions about SQL already on SF but before posing any myself (quite possible due to the project I'm working on) I'd like to find out what others think is the appropriate site to ask such questions. I personally see them as more SO than SF, although the people over there may well disagree. On the other hand, I like the SF community much more and would therefore prefer to ask here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way I see it:
 - SQL *language* questions belong on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
 - Database *server* questions belong on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)
 - Database *tuning* questions belong on [dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: excellent, I came in here expecting to see the usual head-scratching but I am encouraged that .. hey .. someone gets it! (in reality there is a bit more overlap between dba and SF/SO, but the spirit of what you said is correct. I consider dba for 'ninja-level' SQL questions.)

Comment: @Jeff, does that mean we should migrate non-ninja SQL questions to SO? The number we have suggests most SF members don't have an issue with them being posted on SF and I'm happy to go with the flow.

Comment: @john dba is still in beta, but I feel really hard-core database config, tweaking, and tuning questions belong there, while more routine database and server configuration stuff can stay here on SF.

Answer (score 1):

Myself being a DBA and new to Stack Exchange I would agree in part with @KennyRasschaert.

My job as a DBA is to optimize the performance, configure the settings and debug errors on the database engine level, be it Microsoft SQL or Oracle Database Server.

In my job I am not responsible for the configuration and/or tuning of the underlying Windows Server.

From my perspective I would do the following if asking questions regarding an SQL problem:

- SQL DDL (data defintion language) questions would be placed in the DBA.stackexchange.com site (Questions are or can be database specific)
- SQL DML (data manipulation language) questions would be placed in the stackoverflow.com site (SQL DML is based on the ANSI Standard 92 and newer and is nearly the same for any flavour of your database engine)
- Database engine question would be placed in DBA.stackexchange.com site
- Database optimizing/configuration questions would be placed in DBA.stackexchanage.com site
- Questions regarding performace would be first asked in DBA.stackexchange.com and if found to be server questions moved to serverfault.com

You could add more sub-structures to my idea, but it accounts for most questions that could be asked.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. Could you explain why?

Comment: I've got no idea who downvoted you or why, but on meta votes simply indicate agreement. A downvote is someone just disagreeing with you.

Comment: @RobM Thanks for your feedback.