# Change description for database-related tags

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do SQL questions belong?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1330/where-do-sql-questions-belong)
>   [What kind of database/DBA questions does the SF community want to keep?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1855/what-kind-of-database-dba-questions-does-the-sf-community-want-to-keep)

Now that http://dba.stackexchange.com is there, shouldn't we divert the relevant traffic there? I was specifically thinking about tags like mysql or sql-server which explicitly state that DBA questions are on-topic at Serverfault - this seems counterproductive to me. Should not we at least modify the description to directing the users to DBA?

Edit: since there have been a couple of close-as-duplicate votes, I believe there is a misunderstanding - it is not so much about deciding where questions go but about telling users *"consider posting your database-related questions to http://dba.stackexchange.com after reading their [FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq)"* in all database-related tags.

E.g: the [sql-server tag description](https://serverfault.com/tags/sql-server/info) explicitly states:

> - Who would use the code that my question relates to the most, a developer or a DBA? If a developer, Stack Overflow is your place. If a
>     DBA, ask away here.

which it should not, in my opinion.

[database-administration](https://serverfault.com/tags/database-adminstration/info) does not have any description at all, but the name alone is kind of a hint that questions tagged with it would be on topic at DBA.

Comment: One of our moderators is also a moderator on DBA, so this could be an interesting discussion.

Comment: The [tag:sql-server] tag needs an update, for sure - but I'm not sure what's wrong with [tag:mysql]?

Comment: I have been checking with them (in their chat) about possible migration candidate to quote 'we're aiming for advanced SQL, DBA, BI, NoSQL: etc '.

Comment: @BartDeVos - SQL and Database questions are really two seperate areas. Even though there's overlap, they are definately two different things.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Sure they are, but both where addressed in the topic.

Answer (score 2):

We need to have a discussion with the DBA users, so that we can **both** agree what stays and what goes. We did this with webmasters when it launched and as far as I know it's worked pretty well.

The last thing we want to do is flood their site with stuff they don't want.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1855/what-kind-of-database-dba-questions-does-the-sf-community-want-to-keep ?

Comment: Easy. How did I miss that?

Comment: Hmm, apparently I didn't miss it, I commented on it. I just forgot about it.

Comment: I believe the DBA users already stated what they want to have via their [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) - just as I've written in [my comment to Bart's answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/2442/76595) there is a dissonance between the wording of their FAQ and what apparently is the serverfault's folks belief of what should go there.

Comment: What we believe is not as important as what they believe. We need to stuck to their FAQ.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Are you saying that we need to be more aggressive about giving them anything and everything database related?  I'm not sure if I can agree with you there, for the same reason we don't send every Apache/IIS question to Webmasters or every bash question to U&L: overlap between the sites is expected, and as long as the questions are getting well served where they're asked, there's no problem.  Take [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/343159/72586) from this morning as an example: what about our FAQ does that not fulfill to be on topic here?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Not necessarily actively so. I strongly believe in choice - just giving the questioners the information at hand that there **is** DBA where their stuff might be on topic should make it sort out all by itself. The trouble with "too much" overlap is that one site (in this case DBA) might get at risk of being deprived of relevant questions if serverfault is going to try too hard to compete.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Just because there might be a more relevant place for a question, does not mean that we must aggressively migrate it.  There is overlap, that is a fact; drawing a line in the sand at what we estimate to be the center of the gray area and migrating everything that's over the line is not the intent when the overlap was created.

Comment: @ShaneMadden please note how I explicitly voted to **not** aggressively migrate anything but just facilitating an informed decision where it belongs - at the questioner's